# JWT Guest Authentication with Spring

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I am looking this project (https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo) to understand how to work the JWT Authentication. I want to implement the Guest Authentication **with** and **without** credentials (these users aren't in DB). I have modified the class **JwtAuthenticationFilter** to support the **AnonymousAuthentication**, but if I don't send the body in the Request I have the bad request error. I want modify this project to obtain the token without send username and password credentials to server. Is it possibile to do ? Or can I make a guest account ? Can I have a hint ?

```
...
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                    HttpServletResponse resp,
                                    FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

            String token = req.getHeader(this.tokenHeader);
            String username = tokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(token);

            if(username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null)
            {
                UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                if (tokenUtil.validateToken(authToken, userDetails)) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(req));
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                AnonymousAuthenticationToken authguest = new AnonymousAuthenticationToken("anonymous","anonymousUser", AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ANONYMOUS"));
                authguest.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(req));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authguest);
            }
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }
...
```

Comment: To generate a Token, POST call need to be made, which requires Body as **@RequestBody JwtAuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest** checks for a request containing JwtAuthenticationRequest object. Either you can make this body optional  or define new controller using GET for Anonymous token.

Comment: If you need more reference on how to integrate JWT with Spring-Boot, you may also refer: [https://github.com/deepak-java/jwt-spring-boot]